# Think pad led is blinking after wake

Tags: 16.04, thinkpad, wakeup

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 I get the next problem on my ThinkPad E440:

1) My laptop connected to power
2) I suspend it.
3) After wake up - the led indicator on the top of letter "i" starts blinking for ever.

If I wake up my laptop when it is not connected to the power, led is stops after 2 - 4 blinks.

If I reboot my laptop it stops blinking.

I have windows installation alongside, and everything is ok there. So i think it is ubuntu 16.04 specific problem.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug. You can reset the power led after suspend manually. Run the following command as root:

```
# echo '0 on' > /proc/acpi/ibm/led
```

If you have found any other better solution, please tell me.